# javascript/jquery identifying hidden images using dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    $(function(){
    var image = $('img');
    if (image.attr("id") == "webs"){
    $('#hoverpoint').hover(function(){

        $('#websitehov').stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('#websitehov').stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    }
});
```

I'm trying to write a conditional to find whether or not a hidden image is visible or not. Basically when you hover over the images, if a certain image is visible the hover image will be specific to that visible image. This would be fine if they were constantly visible but since they're on a cycle (cycle plugin) fading in and out every 10 secs I can't identify them. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to check for `id == 'webs'`? Sounds like you have duplicate ids? And `var image = $('img')` might give you an array instead of one image

Comment: 'webs' is one of the fading in/out images I'm trying to find, i have one more image which I'm trying to distinguish with the if statement

Comment: So you have more than one image with id 'webs'? IDs should be unique. Your will not work properly if you have duplicate ids.

Comment: no, other image has an id of 'phone' i hadn't included an else{ in my example

Comment: Can you show (a sample of) your HTML? I think the question might make more sense if we can see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have duplicate ids!!!! anyway it will be more logical if you write this block of code like this:

```
$("img").each(function(){

   currentImage=$(this).attr("class");
   if(currentImage=="webs"){
     $('#hoverpoint').hover(function(){
        $('#websitehov').stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
    }, function() {
        $('#websitehov').stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow');
    });
   }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("img").each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
        $('#hoverpoint').hover(function(){
           $('#websitehov').stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
       }, function() {
        $('#websitehov').stop(true,true).fadeOut('slow');
    });
   }
 })
```

Use visible selector

Comment: still not working, instead of the hover image appearing on both images, it's not appearing at all :/

Comment: can you post you all html and js